Error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::iterator_traits' when using Boost's iterator_facade
I'm using Boost 1.84 and C++17 and I've created a polymorphic_iterator class that inherits from boost::iterator_facade. Here's a simplified version of my class:
namespace iterator {

template <typename TValue,
    typename TCategory,
    typename TRef = TValue &,
    typename TDiff = std::ptrdiff_t>
class polymorphic_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
    polymorphic_iterator<TValue, TCategory, TRef, TDiff>,
    TValue,
    TCategory,
    TRef,
    TDiff>
{
public:
    polymorphic_iterator() {}

    template <typename TIter> polymorphic_iterator(TIter iter)
    // ...
};

} // namespace iterator

When I try to use this iterator in my unit tests, I get the following error:
error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::iterator_traits<iterator::polymorphic_iterator<const char, boost::iterators::incrementable_traversal_tag>>'
I thought boost::iterator_facade would provide the necessary traits for std::iterator_traits. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?
For context this is how I make my iterator in my unit tests:
iterator::polymorphic_iterator<const char, boost::incrementable_traversal_tag> iter; 
I tried explicitly defining value_type
using value_type = TValue;
I considered throwing this gross thing away but its not my code and its very coupled.
Here is my attempt at a minimal reproducible example
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <cassert>

namespace detail {

template <typename TValue, typename TRef, typename TDiff>
struct poly_iter_base {
    virtual ~poly_iter_base() {}
    virtual poly_iter_base* clone() const = 0;
};

template <typename TIter, typename TValue, typename TRef, typename TDiff>
struct poly_iter_impl : public poly_iter_base<TValue, TRef, TDiff> {
    TIter iter_;

    poly_iter_impl(TIter iter) : iter_(iter) {}

    poly_iter_base<TValue, TRef, TDiff>* clone() const override {
        return new poly_iter_impl(iter_);
    }
};

} // namespace detail

namespace iterator {

template <typename TValue, typename TCategory, typename TRef = TValue &, typename TDiff = std::ptrdiff_t>
class polymorphic_iterator : public boost::iterator_facade<
    polymorphic_iterator<TValue, TCategory, TRef, TDiff>,
    TValue,
    TCategory,
    TRef,
    TDiff>
{
public:
    typedef boost::scoped_ptr<detail::poly_iter_base<TValue, TRef, TDiff>> iter_ptr;

    polymorphic_iterator() : iter_(nullptr) {}

    template <typename TIter> polymorphic_iterator(TIter iter) : iter_(new detail::poly_iter_impl<TIter, TValue, TRef, TDiff>(iter)) {}

    polymorphic_iterator(const polymorphic_iterator &other) : iter_((other.iter_.get()) ? other.iter_->clone() : nullptr) {}

private:
    iter_ptr iter_;

    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() {
        // Implement increment logic here
    }

    bool equal(const polymorphic_iterator& other) const {
        // Implement equality comparison logic here
        return false; // Placeholder return
    }

    TValue& dereference() const {
        // Implement dereference logic here
        static TValue placeholder; // Placeholder return
        return placeholder;
    }
};

} // namespace iterator

template <typename TIter>
void incrementable_iterator_test(TIter iter)
{
    const char* TestString = "Hello, World!";
    // Test the iter is assignable and copy constructable
    iter = TIter(TestString);
    TIter iter_copy(iter);
    assert(*iter == *iter_copy);

    // Test the incrementability of the iterator
    assert(&iter == &++iter);
    assert(*(++iter_copy) == *iter++);
    assert(*iter == TestString[2]);
}

int main() {
    const char* TestString = "Hello, World!";
    iterator::polymorphic_iterator<const char, boost::incrementable_traversal_tag> iter(TestString);
    incrementable_iterator_test(iter);
    return 0;
}```


Can you post a [mcve], so I can copy & paste it in my compiler, get the shown error and fix it? Now I get very different error error: 'ptrdiff_t' in namespace 'std' does not name a type.

I still cant reproduce the issue. error: object of type 'iterator::polymorphic_iterator<const char, boost::iterators::incrementable_traversal_tag>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted. What compiler are you using?

Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)

One problem is that scoped_ptr cannot be copied. Iterators must be copyable.
Note that boost already has any_range which is built on any_iterator and has the type erasure semantics you seem to be reimplementing.
See e.g. What are the benefits of using boost::any_range?
Note also that this implementation is battle-tested, and by that I mean it has whethered many extremely subtle bugs over time. I'd prefer to use it if you can.
